# ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 Cookie Authentication Fails with HttpPost ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc, antiforgerytoken

When I post a form to an HttpPost controller method that has the "Authorize" attribute, it fails and I get a bad request. If I remove the "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" attribute from the method, it works fine! Is this normal behavior?

My Startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0);
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                    options.Validate();
                });

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Controller SignIn:

```
        // create claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, c_signed_in.FirstName + gFunc.SPACE + c_signed_in.FamilyName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, c_signed_in.Email),
            // new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, c_signed_in.AccountPassword)
        };

        // create identity
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // cookie or local

        // create principal
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

        // sign-in
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal: principal);
```

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]        
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

My View:

```
    <form class="form-group" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SubmitAccountForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @*code here*@

    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your final step is to have your application create the XSRF token in the HTTP request pipeline. At this point, your application is being told to validate against XSRF but no token is being inserted into the request for the server to compare.

In your Startup.cs, add the **IAntiforgery antiforgery** parameter and then the **XSRF config** block below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        // XSRF config
        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

            if (
                string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                path.StartsWith("/Login",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
                // and Angular uses it by default.
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                                                new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            }

            return next(context);
        });
        // End XSRF config
```

...

NOTE: the IF statement simply controls what request path the XSRF token is created for. You just need to make sure it gets created before you need it.

(I added the "/Login" case because when a user logged out they were still at a /Login path in my app and I needed the XSRF token to be refreshed before they tried to login again.)

[Configure antiforgery features with IAntiforgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-antiforgery-features-with-iantiforgery)

Answer (score 0):

The new form tag helper outputs the anti forgery token as part of the from.
(See the following)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms

so perhaps try it like this (edited to show missing code)

```html
  <form class="form-group" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SubmitAccountForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">



    @*code here*@

    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: ValidateAntiforgeryToken seems to work fine in the controller method when there is no "Authorize" attribute. as soon as I add Authorize it fails. are you saying I should try removing the line: @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the form, as its already being added in the form declaration?

Comment: this is so frustrating. now even if I remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the POST method I still get a 404 not found. as soon as I add the [Authorize] it fails, even though I can see that the SignInAsync is working

Comment: Yes sorry that is my understanding of how it should work, I did not include the correct mark up for the code snip so it was missing.

Comment: thanks for your help. I understand that the form constructor automatically adds the AFToken, so I've removed the explicit "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" from the form. [Authorize] in the controller method by itself works fine, but as soon as I add the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] I just get a blank page with 404 error at the top. and I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score -1):

I've spent some more time delving into ASP.NET MVC and also bought an excellent book which I would recommend: "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2" by Freeman. After a lot of digging, it seems that you cannot use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute in a Post method TOGETHER with the [Authorize] attribute. It will throw an exception. I guess if it's authorized then there is no need to validate the token.